# How does the smoothing lambda is calculated in quantreg::rqss?

Tags: r, quantile-regression

I have been working with `quantreg::rqss()` function for non-parametric quantile regression in R (documentation is [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantreg/versions/5.86/topics/rqss)).

And I have a question of what is happening behind the scene with argument `lambda`. I understand it is a smoothening term , but I wonder if someone can explain in *plain language* what kind approach it takes to "smooth" the curve. For example, is it taking the nearest neighboring points like lowess does? or it is something different?

I do not have background in statistics, so reading a suggested [paper](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/%7Eroger/NAKE/qss.pdf) does not make it clear for me.

Thank you a lot in advance!